# Make contigency table for many columns in r?

Tags: r

Say I have the below dataframe (df)

```
Class   Occupation  X   Y
Lower   Agriculture 1   0
Upper   Agriculture 0   1
Upper   Agriculture 1   1
Upper   Agriculture 0   0
Upper   Business    1   0
Lower   Business    1   1
Lower   Business    0   0
Lower   Business    1   0
```

And, I want the summarize the data as below

```
Occupation  X   Y
Agriculture 2   2
Business    3   1


Class   X   Y
Lower   3   1
Upper   2   2
```

Now, I have to do the following method,

```
table(df$Class, df$X)
table(df$Class, df$Y)
table(df$Occupation, df$X)
table(df$Occupation, df$Y)
```

And then I combine the data manually. Can there be a better method, if I had many columns?

Comment: So you're looking for separate tables for each?

Comment: Yes I am looking for separate tables

Comment: You can use the same approach using `data.table` without having to think about constructing `formula`s. The general idea would be something like: `library(data.table); setDT(mydf); cols <- c("Occupation", "Class"); lapply(cols, function(x) mydf[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = c("X", "Y"), by = x])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(cbind(X, Y) ~ Occupation, df, FUN = sum)
#   Occupation X Y
#1 Agriculture 2 2
#2    Business 3 1

aggregate(cbind(X, Y) ~ Class, df, FUN = sum)
#  Class X Y
#1 Lower 3 1
#2 Upper 2 2
```

Another way is `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(cbind(X, Y) ~ Occupation, df)

#Occupation    X Y
#  Agriculture 2 2
#  Business    3 1

xtabs(cbind(X, Y) ~ Class, df)

#Class   X Y
#  Lower 3 1
#  Upper 2 2
```

To do it automatically:

```
lapply(c('Class', 'Occupation'), function(x) {

  myform <- as.formula(paste('cbind(X, Y) ~', x))
  xtabs(myform, df)

})
```

Comment: Now, if I have 100 columns like Occupation, Class, Age etc, I have to do this 100 times.. Can there be a logic where it can be done in one go

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand well you can use `dplyr` package and `group_by` function in order to do that.

You can use `group_by` function and `summarise_each` in the following manner:

```
library(dplyr)
yourdata %>% group_by(Occupation) %>% 
    summarise_each(Occupation,funs(sum),column4:column5)
```

I think this should work in your case.

Comment: Now, if I have 100 columns like Occupation, Class, Age etc, I have to do this 100 times.. Can there be a logic where it can be done in one go